# Editing Audio after cutting into clips - Premiere Pro / Audition

Tags: video, premiere, audio

I have a video with relatively quiet audio. I've already cut my video into clips in Premiere Pro CC, but I want to increase the audio for my entire video without having the volume change from clip to clip, as some have louder moments than others.

If I use "Normalize All Peaks" in Audio Gain, then my volume is different for every clip. If I use "Normalize Max Peaks", then my volume is ok but it's still too quiet.

Is there a way to export the original audio from my video into Audition, edit it there, and then re-import to Premiere without needing to re-cut it?

Using Adobe Premiere Pro CC and Adobe Audition CC.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to use third party plug-ins: Alex Audio Butler ([alexaudiobutler.com](https://alexaudiobutler.com)) is perfect for this: it'll create correct voice levels (even withing clips) automatically for you while you edit.

(disclaimer, I am the developer of this tool)

Answer (score 0):

Each track has a volume control as well in Premiere. You can control volume at the clip level, at the track level, or both. I would suggest using "Normalize Max Peaks" and then boosting the volume of the track.

Comment: if you normalise and then boost the level of the track you'll get clipping. To bring up the quieter section of the track you could try using a compressor filter on the audio in Audition.

Answer (score 0):

Under Clip > Audio Options > Audio Gain, where you should have found the two options you talked about, you can choose "Adjust Gain By" and boost the volume by the amount in dB you specify.
You can then listen to your audio and tweak it again with the same option. To decrease the volume, just enter a negative amount into "Adjust Gain By".

See [Adobe's help page](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/adjusting-volume-levels.html#normalize_one_or_more_clips) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Audio Track Mixer in Premiere, and add a compressor to your channel, but set its ratio to 1:1 (no compression).  Then just use the gain in the compressor's settings to increase the gain of the entire channel.